# ExtJS DataView showing only last JSON element

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I have the following code:

```
new Ext.DataView({
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: 'request/getAssetsJSON',
        baseParams: {
            _id: this.request._id
        },
        root: 'results',
        fields: [ 'attachment', 'id', 'name', 'property', 'type' ],
        autoLoad: true
    }),
    emptyText: 'No images to display',
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<tpl for=".">',
            '<div class="thumb-wrap" id="{name}">',
            '<div class="thumb"><p>Test</p><img height="45" src="request/getAsset?id={id}&attachment={attachment}" title="{name}"></div>',
            '<span class="x-editable">{name}</span></div>',
        '</tpl>',
        '<div class="x-clear"></div>'
    )
})
```

The JSON that gets sent by request/getAssetsJSON is:

```
[{"attachment":"img1.png","id":"4dc90e2a6ba440e37601d5d074011e2e","name":"img1"},   
{"attachment":"img2.png","id":"4dc90e2a6ba440e37601d5d074011e2e","name":"img2"},
{"attachment":"img3.png","id":"4dc90e2a6ba440e37601d5d074011e2e","name":"img3"}]
```

My problem is that the DataView shows only the last image (img3.png) and there is only one GET request to request/getAsset.

I guess something is wrong with how ExtJS iterates over my template, or with how it loads the data, but I am at a loss here.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have same id "id":"4dc90e2a6ba440e37601d5d074011e2e" for all items. You can change json response on server side or create  model for this data and set idProperty : '_id'(default idProperty: 'id')

```
Ext.define('YouModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        idProperty : '_id',
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',          type: 'auto'},

            {name : 'attachment',      type : 'string'},
            {name : 'name',  type : 'string'}
        ]

    }
});

new Ext.DataView({
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        url: 'request/getAssetsJSON',
        baseParams: {
            _id: this.request._id
        },
        root: 'results',
        model: 'YourModel',
        autoLoad: true
    }),
  ....
})
```

Comment: They're supposed to have the same id. That's the CouchDB document ID. The attachment ID is given by the "attachment" property.

Comment: Wow, I just changed "id" to "docId" in the JSON, and it seems to work. That doesn't make sense at all, but ah well, it fixed it! Thanks :)